# Automatically transform a log of check-in/check-out events into a time-sheet

Tags: google-sheets

> UPDATE: Some context: A log that is fed automatically by a IFTTT script contains all check-in and check-outs for employees that work in a factory. I need to build a report with the first check-in for each day, and the last check-out for each day (employees might check-out for lunch, but come back and only the first check-in and last check-out should count).
>
> My current solution is to calculate a "is first checkin or last checkout?" Boolean, and then feed this log into a pivot table for reporting purposes filtering out the repeat entries

My spreadsheet will have data inserted in columns D & E by a third party application (IFTTT or google forms), and I would like to use an arrayformula to automatically calculate one column as data come ins from those applications.

```
(D)Date             (E)Time Calc
January 6, Friday   15:06   TRUE
January 6, Friday   15:15   TRUE
January 9, Monday   8:36    TRUE
January 9, Monday   10:04   FALSE
January 9, Monday   10:37   FALSE
January 9, Monday   15:51   TRUE
```

The formular for Calc is

```
=or(MIN(filter(E:E,D:D=D2,B:B=B2))=E2,MAX(filter(E:E,D:D=D2,B:B=B2))=E2)
```

How can I transform this formula into an arrayformula? From my experimentations it seems that ArrayFormula doesn't mix well with Filter. Help is appreciated!

Comment: It's best to state the actual problem such as "determine whether the value is the highest for that date" instead of pre-supposing a solution (filter inside of arrayformula) and asking about that. [The XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377)

Answer (score 1):

So, the goal is to determine, for each date, whether the value in column E is the highest or lowest for that date. I think this is too much logic to pack into a single formula, but can be expressed by two array formulas. The first one creates two helper columns:

```
=arrayformula(vlookup(filter(D:D, len(D:D)), query(D:E, "select D, min(E), max(E) group by D", 1), {2, 3}))
```

This is itself a combination of two formulas: the inner `query` gets the minimum and maximum of E for each date in D; then `vlookup` aligns these min-max values with the rows of the original table. The filtering by `len(D:D)` is for performance reasons, to avoid looking up a huge number of empty cells.

Suppose the first formula was in G1; then it formed the columns G and H, which leads to E1 being

```
=arrayformula(not((E:E > G:G) * (E:E < H:H)))
```

Note that `and` and `or` are not arrayformula-friendly, but can be replaced by * and + which result in booleans getting implicitly converted to 0-1. The `not` function is array-friendly, and is used here partly to get a boolean back from an integer.

Comment: Thank you zak! I've added some context as per your suggestion, and tried your solution. I could not, however, replicate the results I need using your second array formula (see my full spreadsheet here https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ykOAO5WJy62P0vo-50iytQMpc1mJqNTbdrbVEI7ql10/edit?usp=sharing ). Also, array solution lose the filtering on column B that I had before. The logic of arrayformulas is different than traditional ones and I am still struggling to make them work!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by @zaq, I solved by re-engineering the spreadsheet and got the solution by using the following formula:

```
=query(query(Sheet1!B:E, "select D, min(E), max(E) group by D pivot C,B ", 1),"select Col1, Col3, Col10,Col4,Col11")
```

This formula transforms a log of employee check-in and check-outs into a summarized "hours worked" table that contains,for each day, and for every employee, the first check-in and the last check-out.